# Wordpress Login - Changed URL no access

Tags: wordpress, authentication, url

I started a Google Cloud Account. Setup a Wordpress site. All was good. I changed the URL in the backend of Wordpress to match the new domain. Was not setup right. So I changed the URL back again to the IP address. However, I am locked out. Nothing works. How can I access the Wordpress account to update the URL in case I did it wrong or entered the wrong IP address?

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to access the MYSQL database and manually change it from there, that is if you have access to the database through PHPmyadmin or putty to the server directly.

your problem is not an easy fix sorry, I would recommend burning it down and restore from a backup.